# How to store and consume static data in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Imagine that you've written a pretty abstract table component intended to be used on resource index pages (e.g. `/users`, `/posts`...).

The component has only two basic properties - `resourceName` and an array of `resources` to display. In order to render the table properly you've created a sort of a configuration data structure that is tied to a particular resource type - identified by the `resourceName`. Each resource type is tied to an array of objects which represent the various columns the table has, which properties they display and possibly components to use for displaying the value and which prop to use to provide the value to the component.

```
{
   users: [{
       property: 'id',
       label: 'ID'
   }, 
   {
       property: 'created_at',
       label: 'Time of registration',
       component: 'datetime-showcase',
       passPropertyAs: 'value'
   }],
   //...
}
```

I can see 3 approaches:

1. Directory in the application root where data sits in a js file. The table component accesses the data via `import tableConfigs from '@/config/tables'`. There is a computed property which provides the data as

```
columns() {
 return tableConfigs[this.resourceName];
}
```

2. The data is stored in a central, single vuex module. A computed property with a getter that accepts the resource name is used to retrieve the table configuration.
3. The data is stored in several vuex modules - one for each resource type and a computed property is used to get the data from the state of the appropriate module.

Which way (in terms of maintainability and performance) should these types of data be stored to be used by the table component? I have a similar situation approaching for other components - e.g. one that handles resource index sorting where all that really differs between the various indexes is what can be sorted by and which labels to use.

Comment: Question: why not reduce state locally and create a route/api where the component (or its parent) can get the configs from? Personally I try and limit state where possible.

Comment: What do you mean? As in an async apex API for example? I don't see much point in loading the data over the network because it's used very frequently. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I guess it should be async but that's not really the main point. How much data are you loading? a call over the network for a list of 10 items or so is imo a lot better than managing state in a complex manner (and leads to bugs), a good example is pagination, load each page when clicked no need to handle the data client side.

Comment: @Michael But this data never changes. This is sort of just a static declaration of which columns are to be displayed for a particular resource index table and which components render particular columns if they're not just a simple string. It's basically just settings for a table component that say: If we are displaying a list of users show these columns. I'm not solving the problem of loading the users themselves but how they are displayed to the user.

Comment: If its static then all the more reason for it to come from outside, you can consider using the `keep-alive` component to keep a cache in the event that user leaves the route and returns.

Comment: What is the advantage of getting the data from outside when it is directly tied to the frontend implementation? I don't think that the server should dictate the names of frontend components that the frontend implementation should use. From a maintenance point of view it doesn't make much sense to me.